# Flutter app has error and isn't launching

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am trying to run my flutter app on my iPhone. I was able to do it before, but it suddenly stopped, and I'm getting this error:

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

It appears that your application still contains the default signing identifier.
Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on Jessica's iPhone.
```

Here's what I tried doing:

- Run `flutter clean`
- Restart Computer
- Delete app from phone
- Renamed the bundle Id
- In Xcode, I changed File > Workspace Settings to "Legacy Build System"
- Locked and unlocked keychain
- In Xcode I did Product > Clean Build Folder

None of that made it work. When I try running it in Xcode, I get the following error:

```
460 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
```

When I try running from Xcode on ios Simulator, I get:

```
35 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

(There were other errors before, but this is the latest one.)

How can I run the flutter app on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

there is a github issue [26123](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26123#issuecomment-481101019) with a work around

TL:DR
Target: Runner in Xcode,

[image: Screen Shot 2019-04-09 at 2 42 40 pm]

And then replacing com.example in the Bundle Identifier with the email in my Signing Certificate.

[image: Screen Shot 2019-04-09 at 2 40 09 pm]

Then building in Xcode

Comment: So I would put my email address there? Like "jessicaAllison@gmail.com"?

Comment: yeah , also more data from this quoted comment >>>I followed the advise @LachlanGorst And then replacing com.example in the Bundle Identifier with the email in my Signing Certificate.
In the case my email is myemail@whatever.com than the Bundle
Identifier should be myemail-whatever.com.licenseTest where licenseTest is my app name https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26123#issuecomment-594188046